# jQuery Autocomplete .data("autocomplete") is undefined

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, undefined, jquery-autocomplete

When I try to implement auto-complete using the code below I get an error stating:

```
.data("autocomplete") is undefined
```

How ever if I remove the .data() method from the end it works fine (just with out the customizable graphics that .data() provides). Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

```
$("input#testInput").bind("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {

  }).autocomplete({
      appendTo: "#autoCompList",
      source: function (request, response) {
          $.ajax({

              url: JSONP CALL URL
              dataType: "jsonp",
              data: {
                  featureClass: "P",
                  style: "full",
                  maxRows: 12,
                  name_startsWith: request.term
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                      fbPageJson = item;
                          return {
                              label: item.name,
                              image: item.picture,
                              json: item,
                          }
                  }));
              },
          });
      }

  }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><img src='" + item.image + "' alt='no photo'/></a>" + item.label).appendTo(ul);
  };
```

Answer (score 61):

I had the same problem and based on the 1.10.0 version of jquery ui, I think you should try

```
data('uiAutocomplete')
```

instead of

```
data('autocomplete')
```

Based on Johnny's comment, I checked how the .data() function works. Yes, jQuery returns null from .data() call when selector does not find any items.

So if there is no matching element for your selector, then no autocomplete object is created and added to the custom data object.

So it seems it is better to do this:

```
    $(selector).autocomplete({ your autocomplete config props here });
    if ( $(selector).data() ) {

    // some jQueryUI versions may use different keys for the object. so to make sure,
    // put a breakpoint on the following line and add a watch for $(selector).data(). 
    // then you can find out what key is used by your jQueryUI script.

        var ac = $(selector).data('uiAutocomplete');
        if ( ac ) {
           // do what you want with the autoComplete object. below is the changed version of an example from jqueryUI autocomplete tutorial

           ac._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't they update the documentation with each release, this is so annoying. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe that's because one of the two things we developers hate most is documenting things ? :) And the second must be filling timesheets I suppose

Comment: data('uiAutocomplete') doesn't work for me. Also currently on the jquery-ui demo website they have it as data('ui-Autocomplete'). I think the issue is the .data property itself. It is not defined, no matter with what argument you call it.

Comment: In my version, it is absolutely "uiAutocomplete". You can debug it with Chrome and you'll see the name of the attribute by calling .data()

Comment: JQuery 1.7.2 / JQueryUI 1.10.2 - I'm finding both uiAutocomplete and ui-Autocomplete work just fine!

Answer (score 8):

`data('ui-Autocomplete')` resolved my troubles. I think it's from `jquery 1.7` with `jquery-ui 1.8`. `data('autocomplete')` was ok. The same script with a recent version of these files doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

### I found the solution!

Somepeople think that "ui-autocomplete" is wrong, so they use "autocomplete" or "uiAutocomplete", but that is wrong. Actually, "ui-autocomplete" is the right way to do this.

I have the same issue you have, and I find with a friend the problem of this code. Instead:

```
.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
       if (!_.include(self.idArr, item.id)) {
            return $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
            }
    };
```

Use:

```
._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      if (!_.include(self.idArr, item.id)) {
         return $('<li></li>').data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).append('<a>' + item.name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
           }
       };
```

I think combobox and autocomplete returns a data('ui-autocomplete'), so if you type .data('ui-autocomplete') you're doing something like:

```
.data('ui-autocomplete').data('ui-autocomplete')
```

What's wrong....well, actually I don't know why this don't work and why without this works, but trust me, delete .data('ui-autocomplete') and be happy!

Answer (score 4):

Actually in your success function you are calling `response` and returning an object like

```
return {
           label: item.name,
           image: item.picture,
           json: item,
       }
```

but in the following line

```
return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><img src='" + item.image + "' alt='no photo'/></a>" + item.label + " Number of Likes: " + item.likes).appendTo(ul);
```

you are using `item.likes` that is not available in your returned object, so it's the problem. I think you can use it like

```
success:function(data) {
    var result = $.map(data, function (item){
    return {
            label: item.name,
            image: item.picture,
            item.likes 
        };
    });
    response(result);
}
```

Also keep the `item.label` inside the `<a></a>` (it may not a cause for the error), like

```
return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><img src='" + item.image + "' alt='no photo'/>"+item.label+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
```

and make sure in the following line

```
$.map(data.data, function (item) // notice data.data
```

whether it should be `data.data` or only `data`. You can also remove the `json: item` from the object because you didn't use it anywhere, as far as I'm concerned.

**Update:** Change following line

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {...};
```

to

```
.data("autocomplete")?._renderItem = function (ul, item) {...}; // notice the ? mark
```

or

```
if(typeof $('#Your_Input_Id').val()!="undefined")
{
    $('#Your_Input_Id').autocomplete({....});
}
```

or

```
var mydata=$('#Your_Input_Id').autocomplete(...).data('autocomplete');
if(mydata)
    mydata._renderItem = function (ul, item) {...};
```

Comment: Hi Sheikh, thanks for your response. You are correct that was an error in my code (corrected edit) but it is not the source of the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: Also for test, can you please try to replace this `"<a><img src='" + item.image + "' alt='no photo'/></a>"` with this `"<img src='" + item.image + "' alt='no photo'/><a>item.label</a>"` or just remove the `img` tag completely, only for test, please let me know if it makes any changes.

Comment: The error I'm getting in the console is '.data(“autocomplete”) is undefined'. I get thie even if the data callback function is empty

Comment: Try `.data("autocomplete")?._renderItem`, notice the `?`

Comment: Or wrap your `autocomplete` call inside `if(typeof $('#yourInputName').val()!="undefined"){ $("input#testInput").bind("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {

  }).autocomplete({...} }`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the latest example of combobox on the site demo, you will see they use data('ui-Autocomplete'). I ran into the same problem as you. I was previously using jquery-1.6.2 and jquery-ui-1.8.16.
Once I updated my files to jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-ui-1.10.0 the error was fixed. I assume the older jquery-ui autocomplete was not setting the data('ui-Autocomplete') property, therefore it was null/undefined when retrieved. I hope this helps other people since you probably already fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the below mentioned line

> .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

instate of

> .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

as per the documentation available at Jquery site [Jquery AutoComplete Documentation and example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)  you will find this code.

from upgraded version of jquery 1.10 they have made change in code. hope this will help you.