# JQuery UI autocomplete select on blur or on close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to select the value from my input autocomplete on blur or on close.

I tried to put this in the function of the close parameter but it can't work :

```
close: function() {
  $($(this).data('autocomplete').menu.active).find('a').trigger('click');
  $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all');
}
```

Anybody has a clue ?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10405932/497356

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, thank you, I hacked it according to my needs (select automatically the first value, see my post edit). Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Andrew Whitaker, I got this solution to select the first value automatically when leaving the autocompletion :

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype.options.autoSelect = true;
$( ".ui-autocomplete-input" ).live( "blur", function( event ) {

    var autocomplete = $( this ).data( "autocomplete" );
    if ( !autocomplete.options.autoSelect || autocomplete.selectedItem ) { return; }

    autocomplete.widget().children( ".ui-menu-item:first" ).each(function() {
        var item = $( this ).data( "item.autocomplete" );
        autocomplete.selectedItem = item;
    });
    if ( autocomplete.selectedItem ) {
        autocomplete._trigger( "select", event, { item: autocomplete.selectedItem } );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for jQuery UI - v1.12.1

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype.options.autoSelect = true;
$( ".ui-autocomplete-input" ).live( "blur", function( event ) {
    var autocomplete = $(this).autocomplete('instance');

    if (!autocomplete.options.autoSelect || autocomplete.selectedItem ) { return; }

    autocomplete.widget().children( ".ui-menu-item:first" ).each(function() {
        var item = $( this ).data('ui-autocomplete-item');
        autocomplete.selectedItem = item;

    });

    if ( autocomplete.selectedItem ) {
        autocomplete._trigger( "select", event, { item: autocomplete.selectedItem } );
        autocomplete._value( autocomplete.selectedItem.value );
    }
});
```